# MSAccess - "Unhide Columns" Dialog - via VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, toolbar

I am trying to add a button to an MS Access form, with an embedded table as a subform, to pop open the "Unhide Columns" dialog.

I realize my users can right-click a column to gain access to the Unhide Columns dialog.  I am looking to call that dialog via a button, among some other common table user-manipulation tasks (sort, filter, etc.).

Possible?  Via sendkeys maybe?

Comment: Are they using runtime? If so, they do not have access to column header functions for sorting and such.

Comment: Yes, this button on the form is available at run time.  Maybe I am missing your intent, but I can control the filter/sort of the table embedded in the subform via buttons on the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This opens the UnHide Columns dialog for a table which is open in Datasheet View and which has focus in the Access application window.

```vb
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUnhideColumns
```

I'm unsure whether that will apply directly to your situation, but hopefully it will lead you to something you can use.

When you click the command button, it will have focus.  So in its click event, first `SetFocus` to the table datasheet before calling `RunCommand`.

Comment: Perfect.  Yes, need to SetFocus to the subform first.

Thank you!!